# Kill Stop a query function when the browser exceeds a width

Tags: jquery

When my site is over 640px, I display 4 grids each having their own content, when the website is less than 640px then instead of a grid it turns to a slide allowing the user to scroll through them instead.

This is working fine when the user has a browser over 640px and manually adjusts it to less than 640px, but when they manually adjust it back then it stays as a slide show when it should return to a grid/

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xc2cgs6b/

From what I can work out I need to kill the function but I don't know how.

Here's a snippet of the jquery, this allows me to add the slider code to the if statement but I need to kill it in the else part?

```
   var currentState = false;

function setSize() {

    var state = $(window).width() < 640;
    if (state != currentState) {
        currentState = state;
        if (state) {

        } else {
            $('.swipe-container').unbind();
        }
    }
}

setSize();
$(window).on('resize', setSize);
```

Comment: Instead of killing the slider, can you add/remove some class to it? e.g. `slider-disabled`. Then on `slide`, based on whether the class name is absent/present, you can enable/disable the slider.

Comment: No, tried that but the script has already taken hold of it and removing the class etc does nothing once it's already running.

Comment: I've looked at swipe.js and there doesn't seem to be a way to 'turn it off' at any particular point in time. Is your slideshow simple enough just to write your own scrolling code?